# Python 3 status on requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-requests, tqdm

**Short version:** I am looking at how to implement a progress bar in a Python3 program as print or std out, as my program runs 12k+ HEAD requests with python requests library, on a list of domains. I want to know how far along it is as it goes.

**Details**

I have a script to take a text file from `sys.argv` which is a list of domain names, then using python requests grab the HEAD status of each one, with queue & threading its pretty fast. But if you have 12,000 domains to query, it can take a while.

I want to add the status of the overall file as a progress bar. I have had some success using the below from another post here on stack.

```
    for line in (url):
        global progress
        progress = progress + len(line)
        progress_percent = (1.0*progress)/fileSize
        print("Progress :", progress_percent)
```

But I have this bit of code inside my function that also queues up each URL for the threading and queue, so I still get a new line print for each line and it is a guide more than a proper progress bar that goes to 100%.

I have tried with tqdm but I can't quite get it to do the right calculations, either it doesn't put output at all (?) or it gives a status on each URL as a percent of the total.

Pseudo code the rest of my program is:

```
sys.argv[1]  # get the file  
work_function() # a while true loop that gets a URL from a queue, inside this is the `for line in URL` function    
main() # makes all the head requests, gets response strings writes to different text files.  
for i in range(x): # small threading loop for the `work_function`.  
for loop  # that makes the queue of URLs from the sys.argv file in.
```

My best effort so far has this, any improvement suggestions welcome!

> Progress : 0.7111111111111111
> Progress : 0.7333333333333333
> Progress : 0.7555555555555555

Comment: What is the specific problem? To calculate progress, to print it less frequently, to show it updating on a single line instead of one for each print, something else?

Comment: To put a progress bar for how many of the requests have been made out of the total from a given file on a single line, yes.

Comment: Try `print("Progress :", progress_percent, end="\r")`. The next print will then start at the same line as this. Be aware that if the next print has less characters the characters from previous print remain on screen.

Comment: That is a solid improvement on the print statement I had, a lot cleaner.